# Subclass UIView not loading when initialized in main view

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview

I am trying to create a small indicator inside of a `UIButton`. Ive placed a custom view and changed the custom class in Interface builder to be my class. Ive then created an `IBOutlet` of the same type and connected them in interface builder as well.

My subclass then looks like this:

```
- (UIView *)initWithNumber:(NSInteger *)number
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 34, 17)];
    if (self) {
        [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];

    }
    return self;
}
```

then in the main view I do:

```
self.indicatorControl = [indicatorControl alloc] initWithNumber:(NSNumber *)32];
```

But its not initializing the view and changing the background color when the view loads? Why doesn't this happen? If I put the `setBackgroundColor` method call in `awakeFromNib` it works, but I want it to initialize and return my view when I call my initialization. It seems like this should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you keep the IBOutlet there interface builder will re-initialize your button, overwriting your in-code button creation. Do you want to initialize the button in code or interface builder?

I would suggest:

**Code:** de-link the button from interface builder and put code in viewDidLoad of parent view controller
**Interface builder:** set the background to blue in interface builder or perform initialization in awakeFromNib

Comment: Thank you, I just used the awakeFromNib and set the element up how I wanted and then to hidden, then created a method to set the number that I wanted in the indicator and then it would set itself to not hidden in there... works great.. thanks for the explanation.